# how to implement oauth2 on java restful services

Tags: oauth

I need help with `oauth2.0` and `java` restful (jersey), any help would be appreciated, I need to find way `how oauth2 would be implemented`. Here's the scenario, We have a web based application, now, there are clients engage to it. They're planning to have an `API` (**Restful service**) so that it will be consumed on mobile devices(`android and ios`). (They can login using mobile and update their accounts etc.).

Now, my problem is how will I integrate oauth2 for its security using java and how will I create Authorization server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this library https://github.com/BrightcoveLearning/oauth-client-examples/tree/master/amber-java and works like a charm, thanks to the author.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same question and end up building an open-source project: [srb4j](https://github.com/chenjianjx/srb4j), which is also based on Jersey and OAuth2.

Srb4j has implemented both token endpoints and resource endpoints for you. You can adopt a lot of its code to your own existing system.

Answer (score 0):

<sup># Sorry for this advert, but it may help you...</sup>

**[java-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server)** is a new authorization server implementation in Java (JAX-RS, Jersey, Jetty) which supports **[OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)** and **[OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/)**.

The implementation is *DB-less*, because authorization data (e.g. access tokens), settings of the authorization server itself and settings of client applications are stored in the database on cloud. Therefore, you don't have to set up a database server before starting the authorization server.

Just 4 commands for downloading and starting the authorization server.

```
git clone https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server.git
cd java-oauth-server
vi authlete.properties
mvn jetty:run
```

The source tree of java-oauth-server is very small and customization points are abstracted as SPI (Service Provider Interface), so it will be easy to incorporate the authorization server implementation into your existing web service.

The implementation supports [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) (Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients). It is a new specification (released on Sep. 2015) about a countermeasure against the authorization code interception attack. If you want to expose Web APIs to mobile applications, I recommend that you look for an implementation that supports RFC 7636.

[image]

An explanation about RFC 7636 with graphical figures is [here](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/pkce).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I ended up using this library https://github.com/BrightcoveLearning/oauth-client-examples/tree/master/amber-java and works like a charm, thanks to the author.